# Get Group id of product in Order in a Hook

Tags: php, whmcs

In my website i have created a custom hook. here is my code :

```
<?php function myActionHookFunctionvars($vars) {

    $orderid = $vars['orderid'];
     $ordernumber  = $vars['ordernumber'];
     $amount  = $vars['amount'];

//here i need the group id of the product in which it lies.
}
 add_hook("AfterShoppingCartCheckout",1,"myActionHookFunctionvars");?>
```

So, in this I need to get the information of the group(gid) in which this product which we are ordering lies. As I wants to apply this hook for only products of a specific group, not for all the groups.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please remember that tags are not keywords - stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question doesn't help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to the above mentioned question question.
Put the code below amount variable in function :

```
$gidsql = "SELECT gid FROM `tblproducts` WHERE id=(SELECT packageid FROM `tblhosting` WHERE orderid=$orderid)";
     $gidresult = mysql_query($gidsql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($gidresult)){

        $mygid = $row['gid'];
    }
```

It may useful to anyone.